# Lab colleague uses cracked software. Should I report it?

Tags: etiquette, copyright, software

I've just (accidentally) found that one of our colleagues in the lab (who is a graduate student) uses a cracked piece of software on his personal laptop (We were talking near his station and a pop up went up and warned about the fake license of the software).

The software is an expensive one whose student version is freely available on our shared server; however, the student version's features are often not sufficient for our tasks. So I realize that he might have to do this to handle his job. I don't know if the supervisor is aware of this.

All in all, as it's not acceptable to ignore the copyright, should I report this issue to any responsible sector?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48293/discussion-on-question-by-a-loc-lab-colleague-uses-cracked-software-should-i-re). Further comments will just be deleted, as they can't be moved to chat more than once.

Answer (score 284):

I don't feel that general academic ethics obliges you to report this, unless you have reason to believe that it might be endangering the research of the lab (giving inaccurate results, introducing viruses to lab computers, etc).

You will have to make your own judgment as to whether you are obliged to report by any of the following: your own personal code of ethics, your institution's policies, your lab's internal policies, your PI's expectations, threat of lawsuit from the software vendor, your local law, or likely consequences from any of the above for failing to report.  You could also consider whether to warn your colleague and give them a chance to remove the cracked software before reporting them.  But all of that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: While the accepted answer might feel better, this answer is far more relevant and neutral.

Even brining it up to your supervisor is overstepping one's role without proper risk being established.

Comment: cracked software has hard-to-detect anti-features bug (example cracked version of a engineering software may use in computations slight less material resitance, so that buildings created with it have a greater cost, or just more material resistance so that buildings you create with it just implodes because computations are wrong

Comment: @DarioOO This would be rather unethical on the part of the software developers. They would consciously lead someone to build a building that would collapse, potentially killing people in the process, in retribution for pirating their software?

Comment: @DarioOO I doubt that. If someone built a building using said software and someone died to the incorrect calculations I'm pretty sure the software house would risk a lot, *even if* the software was pirated. In any case,fun fact: I know a software house released a pirated version of their own game about software houses, and in the pirated version they changed a few parameters so that it was impossible to proceed further than a certain point in the game because all the games you tried to produce in-game were pirated and you couldn't sell the copies of the game to anyone.

Comment: @Bakuriu oh yeah, I remember hearing about that! Wasn't that one of those facebook type games where you make and sell things to customers?

Comment: @Bakuriu to sue someone over their product you must have a contract with them. Pirated software is not a contract.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ethical or not, be aware that such measures are not unheard of.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev And I expect companies engaging in such practices to be prosecuted into the ground if they get caught and it results in injury or death... You don't need a contract to sue someone because you happened to be in a building designed to collapse, just because someone valued their intellectual property above human life. Consider that a burglar can sue, and win, someone for booby-trapping their home and they get injured. Courts tend to value human life above property. The opposite sounds psychopathic to me, frankly.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi booby-trapping is an intentional action. How do you prove a software bug is intentional? Anyway, engineers design buildings, not software packages, and if a court discovers that engineers designed a house that collapsed using cracked software, those guys do risk prison sentences for negligence.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Also, have you ever read a software license? Did you ever come across the lines "THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES ARE DISCLAIMED"? They are there exactly for this reason: to protect the authors against such kinds of prosecution. If you find this psychopathic, don't click on "I Agree".

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You can write whatever you want in a software licence... It doesn't mean it's legal or true. If the SE user agreement (which I expect you have read in full obviously) included a clause that said you agreed to them killing you if they felt like it, would you think that's fair or legal? Spoiler alert it's not and no court in the world would uphold that licence. Well, you can write that you decline responsibility all you want, you still need to convince the court....

Comment: The law isn't a game of "gotcha" as some people might believe. There is an investigation before the trial, if they find out that legitimate copies produce good buildings but bad copies produce buildings that collapse, you can argue it's a "bug" all you want but I doubt you will find any sympathy.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Again: software doesn't design buildings, engineers do (and are paid for it). It's their responsibility to make sure they use the right tools, and they will get sued if they don't. Try starting your car without the key by shorting some wires, making an accident and then complaining against the car manufacturer that your brakes didn't work.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev If the car manufacturer booby trapped the car so that the brakes stopped working if you didn't use the key, I would certainly expect them to be liable... Your attitude is incredible.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi My car **actually locks the steering wheel if it detects the key is not there**, which certainly that can lead to a crash if happens while driving. This is an intentional "booby trap" to prevent car theft. But I'm pretty sure I'll be screwed if my insurance finds out I was driving without the key. Same as you, I'm wondering if we're from the same planet.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The steering wheel lock is designed to lock the wheel while the car is parked. It should prevent theft, it should not "punish" the thief. If the device would have been designed *intentionally* to engage while driving, that would lead to the car designer/company being prosecuted for homicide (if the thief died). Almost no jurisdiction I know of allows taking the justice in one own hands. The software could legally "call back home" and alert the company, so it could sue the "hacker" or the user, but only a court is allowed to dispense a penalty.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev BTW, there was not so long ago the [FTDI scandal](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/10/ftdis-anti-counterfeiting-efforts-sit-between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place/), where a software driver intentionally damaged products containing a counterfeit chip, instead of simply refusing to work with that product. It has brought shame on FTDI.

Comment: @DarioOO - "cracked software has hard-to-detect anti-features bug..." If the software can detect that it has been cracked, then it will (should) be able to make the software non operational, or force it to operate in a time-limited "trial" mode, or something similar. If, instead, the software creators intentionally cause the software to silently fail in a way that is destructive to life or property, then they bear some responsibility for the outcome. Of course, the software user who used the unlicensed software will likely have some responsibility as well.

Comment: nope, if the software stop working istantaneously, crakers will just investigate to find why it don't work. If the bug is hard to detect crakers will just release it as "OK". Also there's no one preventing crakers to introduce new bugs (willingly or unwillingly). We had a teacher showing how the craked version messed up mechanical resistance of a gear.

Answer (score 186):

I would stay away from his "personal laptop" in the future and avoid peeking at other people's "very personal" screens. It is not your job to report this. And you should not be looking at other people's screens. He decided to use the software on his personal station, not on the resources of the university, so it is none of your concern. It is a typical "none of your business" case.

Comment: Not quite, since the laptop is used in university premises. What if the software reports its cracked status from the university's IP address, and their IT department gets contacted by the software manufacturer?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Still not the OP's problem. The IT department may decide to track down the infringer, not the OP. And I fail to see why a piece of software would decide to report its cracked status home with IP and all, instead of simply refusing to start on the user's computer.

Comment: @T.Verron What about illegal downloads? Alcohol? Recreational drugs? Where do you draw the line? Concerning the second point, you report cracked status so you can take legal action, isn't that obvious?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev To each his own, but I draw the line where it starts to impact me or the overall quality of the work directly, aka where it becomes my problem. E.g. alcohol while working, or downloads slowing down the network for everyone. Also, it may depend on your country: maybe some countries require by law that illegal behavior be reported.

Comment: Because it is not a grievious offence. You can download pirated software, if you buy a license it is no longer a problem, if the origin is problematic(download site) you can make a checksum check (md5, sha256). Why would it be a crime to have a license that is expired? oh i get around to it at the end o the month or the next. As a software publisher you often do not want the customer to uninstall the software, because then you risk is much higher that the user will find an alternative. So yeah it is counterproductive to think of it as a huge deal and a larger crime.

Comment: Clarification: i do not think there is a law that states specifically after how long the license expires, that it becomes illegal to have the software installed.

Comment: @cognacc So, you draw the line at grievous offences, and apparently this opinion is shared by many people in academia. I must say I'm surprised, but oh well.

Comment: Alternate scenario: "I noticed my colleague uses the word `password` for his password.  Should I report this security issue?"  Personal computers are the responsibility of the person using it, not nosy people around it.

Comment: "you should not be looking at other people's screens" -- I've had a colleague literally standing behind me staring at my screen (uninvited) while I was working. I so much hate it when people do that.

Answer (score 41):

Are you sure it is cracked software ? A 'warning' popup could just be phishing malware and you might expect that a feature to detect piracy would just shut the application down rather than just issue a warning. Equally it could be a prompt to upgrade to a different version or just an expired demo version which is no longer usable.

Perhaps a more immediate issue is if you aren't legitimately being given the right tools for that research you are doing.

Equally you are not really under any obligation to report possible civil crimes on the basis of fairly slim evidence (what you have said here probably wouldn't stand up in court) and if it is a student using a commercial version of software which has a free student version we are talking about quite a fine ethical line in the sense that it may be *just* illegal but it is unlikely that anybody really cares.

While I would certainly not advocate using pirated software this is still at the stage of an suspicion and any formal accusation is either going to result in nothing happening or a lot of trouble for your colleagues to no real constructive purpose.

It is also worth considering that the software distributor may not really care about personal use of unauthorised copies by students as they are really in the business of providing bulk licenses and technical support to commercial users but would be compelled to prosecute if it was bought to their attention.

As an aside we can also **speculate** that providers of software who want to make it the industry standard are fairly keen for students an academic researchers to use it and get to know it, which is why they provide free academic versions. We could even speculate further that this is why this is why they are not quite as rigorous as they perhaps could be in embedding anti-piracy features. while they can't be seen to give away the full version they may not care too much (an may not want to find out) if the odd junior researcher sneaks a cracked copy even though this is clearly wrong and not to be recommended.

Comment: *would be compelled to prosecute if it was brought to their attention* -- that's not how law works, at least where I live. It's always the choice of the damaged part to sue or not.

Comment: They might be compelled in the sense that not prosecuting known infringements of IP rights can be seen as tacit permission which opens up a whole can of worms for them

Comment: "they can't be seen to give away the full version" Some do, if you ask nicely. `:)`

Comment: +1 For pointing out that a pop up means nothing. Sometimes you get them with the proper license too.

Comment: _"you might expect that a feature to detect piracy would just shut the application down rather than just issue a warning"_ Actually, any software developer worth their salt who wishes to engage in licensing knows that they're better off doing it this way.

Answer (score 30):

Before telling anyone, consider what would happen if he, or other grad students, found out you were the snitch.  You'll have to work with these people for years to come, and there is no such thing as "anonymous reporting."  You'll have to make a judgement call as to if you want to get involved.

If you choose to get involved, **do not mention anything in email, go directly to YOUR supervisor.  Explain what YOU have seen, and do not mention hear-say.**  After this, it's in your supervisors hands, don't mention it again.

Comment: +1, exactly. Such a person would not be feeling very welcome in many organizations afterwards. They may also easily lose some reputation with the supervisor – if nothing else, because they are putting extra unpleasant and nonacademic work / responsibility on them.

Answer (score 20):

The key here is 'personal laptop' which I assume means 'purchased with personal, not university funds'.  Here's the reason:

The penalty levied on any institution for evidence of pirated software can be huge, including fees and/or restricted access to said software. (Imagine Microsoft decided to revoke all license for Word. They likely wouldn't, but they can according to their license agreement).

If it were an institutional computer, as a representative of your institution you'd be doing them a favor by alerting someone (anyone) above you. But this seems not the case. If it is a personal laptop, the onus is no longer on you. That person could still pay a penalty, though unlikely, but that would be outside the bounds of your duty to protect the interests of your institution.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer.  But I'm not convinced there is such a hard line between a university computer and a personal device that is being used for work purposes.

Comment: Piracy cases are often tracked by IP address, which in this case will be identified with the university, so you can still get the institution in trouble even if the computer is your own.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev When you write that "[p]iracy cases are often tracked by IP address", do you mean downloading pirate software or using pirate software? If the first, there is nothing in what the OP writes that suggest his colleague downloaded it using the university's network, and if the second could you please provide a source for a case in which someone is tracked via their IP by simply using pirate software?

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f Ever heard of [windows genuine advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage)? Here's a court case: [Microsoft is tackling a Windows 7 pirate (with help from logged IPs)](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/microsoft-tackling-windows-7-pirate-help-logged-ips/)

Comment: Still, the student may (probably?) have signed "I won't use cracked software" with their paperwork connecting them to the lab - which will influence how much responsibility is assigned to the university.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev But that case involve an operating system, not a software. If I understand the OP correctly, he is talking about a specific software (e.g. Autocad, MS Word, Photoshop etc.) and I have never heard of a single case in which someone got tracked using pirate version of those via their IP addresses, which is what you seem to have stated above.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f: No one will take you seriously when you say things like "an operating system, not a software".  Operating system software is software.

Comment: @Ben Voigt You are complete right about an OS being a software, my mistake. What I mean to say was that the OP speaks of application programs as opposed to OSes. I don't know if "no one will take me seriously" as you say, but what I argue is that besides the odd case of a pirate OS copy being tracked down via the IP address during the activation (and more specifically, Windows OS) I have never heard of a similar case involving an application program, at least as of 2016. I would be happy to change my view if a case disproving it is provided, by right now I think this is only scaremongering.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f So the mechanisms for tracking crackers by IP address do exist. I'm not sure if it will be any consolation to the OP's colleague if they are the first to be brought to court over *application* software piracy.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f: "[To deter piracy, Adobe makes its installation disks "phone home" via the Internet to verify themselves.](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/52277182/ns/technology_and_science-tech_and_gadgets/t/adobes-piracy-proof-software-already-pirated/)"

Answer (score 16):

Have you considered simply **talking to your colleague** about the issue?

I don't agree that this is "none of your business" case, since the computer is used in university lab, most probably connected to university network. So the university is affected by whatever risks cracked software may bear (viruses and such), and any piracy tracking will probably identify the offender as having university IP address. This may result in trouble for both your colleague and the university.

However, without solid proof you should not assume anything. Ask your colleague about the software. Chances are, they have a reasonable explanation for the error message you've seen: they may have a legit free trial version which expired, connection issues preventing license validation, missing license token etc. If they admit using cracked software, tell them it's against university policies (it almost certainly is), and give them a chance to fix the situation.

Escalating the issue right away and without warning will not win you any friends (not even your supervisor). Additionally, discovering cracked software on someone's **personal** laptop may lead to question about your own ethics. Depending on how you present the situation, you may be seen as either accusing someone without sufficient proof, or accessing someone's computer without permission.

Comment: This is the obvious and **only** correct answer, from my viewpoint.  It's not that hard to talk to your colleague.  Moreover, it doesn't get them in trouble, it doesn't remove your option of reporting them, and it could, all by itself, have the desired effect that they will decide that it's really *not* okay to use cracked software (since they feel the peer pressure), and stop using it.  Without getting any legal action or disciplinary action involved.  +1, wish I could upvote this multiple times.

Comment: There are certainly scenarios where a warning message may appear when in fact the software has been legitimately purchased. Assuming that cracked software is being used is wrong and could have unpleasant repercussions.

Answer (score 15):

You're looking at the problem from the wrong angle. The problem is **not** with your colleague violating copyright on a piece of academic software. The problem is that your lab **hasn't purchased the necessary tools** to complete whatever line of research you're currently pursuing.

Here's what I would personally do:

1. Ask the student what license they're currently using and if they need the lab to provide one.
2. Talk to your supervisor about purchasing a license for the lab. Since there's a free academic license for that particular software, I presume a full license for an academic institution shouldn't cost an arm and a leg.
3. Once the license is purchased notify the student and ask them to replace the license with the one from your lab.

That's it. No need to point fingers or accuse anyone of misconduct.

Comment: This isn't the issue. a) Having written both academic and commercial purchase orders for several different software, I can tell you it's often not affordable. b) It's not the OP's responsibility to do this. It's either the student or the supervisor. c) Anyway it's that student's personal laptop, not a lab machine. Installing academic-licensed software on someone else's personal laptop, which they'll presumably take with them in future, and maybe use commercially, is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @smci "It's not the OP's responsibility to do this" then they shouldn't get involved in the first place

Comment: JonathanReez that's exactly what I just told you.

Comment: By the way I also dealt with situations where we did bust our asses to purchase and provide access to academic copies (on a server, in cases when we couldn't afford a lab-wide license), but students didn't want to run a remote-session (from home, offsite, at weekends etc.). So, even when you do what you recommend, it still doesn't solve the problem. So just leave it.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you talking with your supervisor about the case **under wraps**. Either she is aware of the case or not, you can rely on her to handle the situation.

I'm a graduate student in a North American university, where utilization of such cracked licenses for personal use is not only common among students, but also between faculty members! It is not something deserving, but it's a fact.

So, as I guess your supervisor is aware of the case, your report may make some trouble for your colleague **and your supervisor**, too. You better watch out...

Comment: And what if my supervisor does confirm such usage? It is, by default, against the rules.

Comment: Then, at least you can convince yourself that you have talked to someone `with some degrees of authority` about it to do something. If she doesn't, it's not you fault...

Comment: OP needs to mind their own business. It's on someone else's personal laptop, and OP couldn't keep their prying eyes off their screen. It has zero impact on lab work, and is a personal ethical choice to make. I see OP accepted this answer because you told them what they wanted to hear, but clearly this opinion is in the minority and frankly, I personally would find is distasteful if someone reported me to an authority figure without jurisdiction over my personal belongings.

Comment: I agree with @SnakeDoc, this answer "feels" right but it isn't the best advice and puts personal ethics over professional ones.

Comment: It feels right because the issue reflects the OP's personal values, but the environment does not allow said values to be enforced upon someone else's personal belongings.  Reporting unlicensed software on people's personal laptop to their work supervisor is **NOT** the right thing to do.

Comment: Can we please *just stop* to say "mind your own business" to people who discover unlawful behaviors? This attitude is really annoying and sad.

Comment: Well does the message say "This is an ILLEGAL License", or does it say, "missing/invalid license, go to www.awesomecompany.com to renew", it is not illegal to have installled a product at then the license is obsoleted. Also some license keys can be invalid later in life, as seen time after time with Microsoft licenses. Many times if a license is invalid or nonexistent you don't press charges etc but allow the user to install a new license and often allows the software to work, sometimes partly in the mean time. If i was a soccer/football referee i would say that is an unbookable offense. ;)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I agree that generally you should report unlawful behavior; however, most people put their own ethics over law. For example even if it was unlawful to criticize the government, many people would not report you for doing so, because they believe it's not evil. With piracy it's similar: many people don't believe it to be evil if not done for profit; especially if one can't afford the license.

Comment: @user31389 TBH I don't want to enter the debate about people who try to justify their piracy actions again. I just wanted to say that such an attitude is really terrible. One could say "you are not obliged to report it", but "mind your business" does sound extremely rude especially when someone wants to do the right thing (i.e. reporting and/or preventing further piracy).

Comment: I have a legitimate license to an expensive piece of EDA software, which is enforced via a USB key. Sometimes I run it without plugging in the key, in which case it works to an extent - but with a pop-up saying that it is unlicensed.  I hope this isn't a similar situation.

Comment: If the colleague mentioned narrowly escaping a speeding ticket because the camera happened to be out today, should that be reported to the supervisor, too? What if the colleague was seen dropping a piece of litter or jay-walking? If it should be reported to somebody, why think it is the supervisor who is the appropriate person? There is a difference between 'X ought not to do A' and 'Y ought to report X to Z for A'. It depends a whole lot on who Z is and the nature of A.

Comment: @JeannePindar Generally when it comes to licensing companies care more about following the spirit of the rules rather than the letter. Probably because in order to claim damages from someone you need to have lost something. So long as you have an appropriate license, running without the USB key generates no loss for them, unless you are distributing the software so that others can run it without the USB key.

Comment: I also have licenses to two or 3 pieces of software that were reporting said lacking of licenses for 2 or 3 days last time I reinstalled my laptop...

Comment: (-1) This is not the situation where immediate escalation (reporting to authority) is called for. There's time enough for escalation iff talking to the student in question reveals that a) there is really cracked software in use, and b) they react nasty to a *very polite* request to consider stopping to use illegal software (ideally accompanied by an offer helping e.g. with the paperwork to get legal access to the missing features at work).

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto. How do you know it's illegal? Your making a huge leap of bad faith from the information provided. Many options exist for this not to be illegal. Your adding 2+2 and getting 8. So many other options exist that could mean this is not illegal. When I am off my home network one of my licenses pops up a warning like this and I am not doing anything illegal. Your are just not correct to assume this is illegal.

Comment: Just to add another example: I use Sublime Text 2 without having purchased a license. This results in periodic pop-ups asking me to purchase a license -- which would appear to be illegal -- but in fact the developers of Sublime Text explicitly state that "evaluation is free" and "there is no enforced time limit on the evaluation". It's designed so that if you have the means to purchase a license (and promote development), you're encouraged to do so; however, for students/others with limited funds, you are not *required* to purchase a license. (And once I'm no longer a student, I intend to!)

Comment: The described warning is not about an expired or otherwise ongoing trial. OP specified it is about a "fake license". My comment was talking about the general case anyway.

Answer (score 7):

It is not your job to enforce or report copyright law so you should not report it. Contrary to what others say here you are not complicit in a crime because it is a matter of civil law and not criminal law, so you have no obligation to do so. Legal matters aside, reporting a colleague will make it hard for you to find support in your future academic life, which is critical for all but the most trivial assignments.

Answer (score 3):

I know there are a lot of answers here, and most of them are the same.  I'm going to go a different direction.

It is entirely possible that the software is
a) demo
b) just expired
c) actually legally purchased and the warning is an error
d) legally purchased, however the person cracks it to avoid a dongle, CD check   or something else archaic and disruptive.
e) something that they purchased from a non-reputable vendor and they didn't know
f) some other plausible deniability.

Thus the result is a recommendation the same as above.  "Not my circus, not my monkeys."

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself:

**Is it my business?**

If no, it's a sign that you might be procrastinating. Strictly forbid yourself to do anything in this case.

If yes, ask yourself why? Would this fact affect you in a positive or in a negative way? Answering this question will provide you with a hint on what to do next, if at all. Just for the sake of an example, if it is the case that using the cracked software might really become visible over the net such that the police might come and seize the equipment including the one you need for your research, then you should probably talk to the colleague and then to his/her boss.  But things might be different if software cracking is a part of research activity; then your colleague publishes on that and gets grant proposals accepted; you should support that to the extent permitted by the law!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't care much if an individual has been using the software for the personal needs. Even software vendors themselves are not interested in punishing a single person. There is no real value for them in making a precedent: upon receiving a miserable surcharge they loose time, resources and often gain negative reputation (vendor *vs* institution is a different story though).

Sooner or later this person is going to present the results of his/her work in a form of annual report, presentation, paper, etc. If a paid version of program has been used for conducting a research, it always shows, and people from the same field will always be aware of what piece of software has been utilized.

Assuming you care about this person and you want to help, I'd suggest to show him/her some free open-source alternatives. Show the benefits of [reproducible research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility#Reproducible_research). Sometimes people use the cracked version not because they are evil, but because they are lazy and don't want to check out for the optimal tools, downloading the first program Google spoonfed them with.

If you want to make it public, on the next group meeting congratulate the person on the achievements and ask politely how this, that or the other has been achieved (which algorightm, how it's been plotted etc.), forcing the person either to lie, or to evade the questions entirely. If the people around are literate, invested and pay attention, they will get your message. If they aren't, your accusation-driven report won't change anything anyway.

I see only one reason you need to report to your supervisor explicitly: if you *have* to collaborate with that individual and you cannot perform your part because you also need to use that pirated program to process the data. Otherwise I'd say it's none of my business. I get my own life and I'd better think for myself.

Answer (score -7):

You should immediately contact the responsible authorities, and report what you have seen, otherwise you will definitely be complicit in a crime, and could yourself be prosecuted for failing to act. This is called 'accessory after the fact'. You should not put yourself at risk by remaining quiet. Remember Edmund Burke's adage "The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing".

Nobody should be doing research with pirated or cracked software; it is unethical, and the results will be compromised. No cure for cancer was ever developed by criminal software thieves.

Erich Mielke

Comment: Accessory after the fact for using pirated software?! Show me one case law precedent on this.

Comment: You sound like the OP just witnessed a school shooting.

Comment: obligatory reading material https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/right-to-read.en.html

Comment: Downvoted for factual incorrectness. This is a matter of civil law, not criminal law.

Comment: While (as?) this sounds perfectly in line with what "the original" Erich Mielke would have liked (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Mielke) - is this a troll post?

Comment: @cbeleites yes, it's obviously meant ironically.

Comment: Seriously?! "Complicit in a crime"?! You made my day buddy :)) Really funny guy...

Answer (score -10):

Report it to the vendor. They are the victim. If this is MATLAB, then it can be reported on the following web page:

https://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/policies_statements/report_piracy.html

Comment: It is supremely ironic that the scale of votes on these answers is inversely proportional to the correct action. So, the most unethical answer gets the most votes, the wishy washy kind-of-anonymously-report-it-to-vague-authorities gets a few votes, and the recommendation to report to the correct entity which will take positive action gets downvoted.