# Is it safe to use pirated software for Doctoral research?

Tags: publications, thesis, software

I am using unlicensed simulation software (downloaded from torrents) for Doctoral Thesis (and Research papers) on my personal laptop without the knowledge of my institution as the university doesn't have the licensed software. 1) Is this safe?
2) Can I be questioned by the software vendor. 3) Can my paper be retracted from journals?

(I'm uninterested in answers relating to free student versions of software and freeware.)

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79603/lab-colleague-uses-cracked-software-should-i-report-it?rq=1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73214/discussion-on-question-by-numero-uno-is-it-safe-to-use-pirated-software-for-doct).

Answer (score 7):

It’s not OK to use unlicensed software. I would suspect that advisors would be very concerned about one of their students using an expensive software package for which they didn’t have a license, since they might have liability for letting you use it.

If it’s so important, then you should talk to your advisor about getting a license.

While I am not personally familiar with people having degrees revoked for using unlicensed software, I could certainly sympathize with arguments calling for sanctions against people who do so.

Comment: I would strongly object to a degree being revoked for using unlicensed software. It's a civil justice matter; the software company may give them a fine, but knowledge acquired is knowledge acquired and this shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I lile your argument, but imagine someone doing unethical experiments on human participants. They may acquire knowledge; their methods are not ethical; their degree is likely to be revoked because of the latter. Knowledge itself is not sufficient.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov The underlying ethical questions are different, so it is hard to generalize like this. There is no direct personal harm involved in using unlicensed software, and so it is harder to apply the same sanctions as when humans are involved (which will usually also be _criminal_, not civil).

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek Using unlicensed software is often directly punished by the university. Eg using torrent itself can be enough to kick out a student in many countries.

Comment: @Greg wow, that is pretty serious, do you have any sources that support your claim? I observed in a number of european countries that the "torrenting community" is very much represented in student culture.

Comment: @user3209815 Just because something is illegal it doesn’t mean no one does it. Eg in Japan the IP of the whole lab is shut down and they start an investigation if anyone runs a software using torrent protocol (including Opera browser).

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek Actually, unethical experiments may be perfectly legal. Stanford experiments were legal. Today, misinforming participants about the goal of research is not illegal, but still unethical.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Any decent university will have a policy explicitly demanding that you stick to ethical experiments. The same is not true for pirated software.

Comment: @sgf It took me 5 sec to google a counter-example: http://accc.uic.edu/policy/software-piracy Feel free to find out more.

Comment: @Greg I was writing in the context of revoking degrees, and not of active students, the latter which can be held to other standards than academic (e.g. housing regulations).

Comment: -1. OP was asking "is it safe", not "is it OK".

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: There is no difference between using pirated software and using for instance scihub articles. By the logic of this "answer" we should fire all academics who use SciHub. Sounds like a good way to increase the chances for getting tenure track positions for some...

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov That link is broken by now, but I don't think it really was a counterexample to a negated universal. (But maybe my comment was misleading. By "any", I meant "every".)

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting topic.

To your questions:

1) Is it safe? Probably not.

2) Can I be questioned by the software vendor? Probably not.

3) Can my paper be retracted from journals? Probably not.

You would have to be sure that you don't get caught. If you are doing your doctoral research at a bigger university you might slip through the cracks because somewhere in your univeristy is using a legit license of the software. In this case it is unlikely that the software company would actually investigate if you are using a license. If you are doing your doctoral research at a smaller university your work might be unnoticed and the software company won't investigate further. But Google Scholar will find everything in case they would want to investigate.

The software company could ask you if you have a license which would be their last step in the investigation. In most cases that happens when someone is using a company outside normal business hours or in a completely different IP range than normal. In your case the software company would only see you using a cracked license. I never heard about software companies who are creating simulation software actually asking reserachers regarding their licenses. But they are fully aware of some researchers using unlicensed software.

If your paper can be retracted from journals could depend on the journal guidelines. The software company would probably see it as some form of advertisement. I would be more worried about your doctoral thesis and your relationship with the university if $h!t hits the fan.

Side note: I know cases where researchers got licenses for simulation software from the software companies. If it's a good project they might support you and are interested to get the results published. They always want to see practical applications for their sotware published because that is the kind of advertisement.

Side note 2: What is wrong with your university? You are doing doctoral research with unlicensed software. Isn't your thesis advisor concerned with how you are obtaining results and the software you are using? And why did you get a research topic when your university doesn't have the actual tools for it?

Comment: @aeis. My university is having an older version of the software.

Comment: @NumeroUno Why not using that version?

Comment: Now I would do.

Comment: So you cracked a software instead of using the older version that exists within your university. I don't understand this mess...

Comment: I haven't used it yet. Iam just clarifying everything before using it.

Comment: I am thinking to work on that cracked software because it is installed in my laptop and I can work on it while I am in home as well.

Comment: @NumeroUno Why not just ask the university to provide you with a licensed copy of the software? Presumably the university/your advisor would have a budget for things like this, probably labelled as something like "research expenses".

Comment: Most expenisve software I use for research is available via my university for free (the university has a site wide license for Matlab for example) and pretty much all software I need that the university doesn't have a license for has an academic license which is a fraction of the price of a commercial license. They want you familiar with their software when you graduate so you recomend it to future employees I guess. So there's not really any excuse to used pirated software for research.

Answer (score 6):

In many countries it is forbidden to use unlicensed software. Hence, using unlicensed software might result in litigation against your university,* which might lead to your dismissal. Thus, it is *unsafe* to use such software.

*There are cases when software vendors have litigated against universities. But, it is difficult to know how many, because universities and software vendors will likely want to settle in private.

---

Having edited the OP's question, I now note that unlicensed software is being used on the OP's personal laptop. Hence, litigation against the university might be difficult, but perhaps not impossible (since the research is most likely owned by the university).

Comment: Is there any documented case of a university being sued or prosecuted as a result of one of its members using pirated software on their personal computer?

Comment: Yes, my first search result is "Westchase Consultancy...has taken the Women’s University in Africa...to the High Court seeking to recover over $418 000." Of course, we should not expect too many results, because universities and software vendors will likely want to keep settlements private.

Comment: Guaranteed they want to settle out of court, newspapers, in fact all parties agree to keep quiet ... A colleague of mine wanted to leave his teaching post - talked to me saying "I have to wait 6 months..." I said go and talk to the dept head and see what they say : one month later he was back in industry, and they had another person to teach as well : the Uni and Industry work together (at least the Uni I was at had HUGE ties with several manufacturers) so no noise, no fuss and swapping people continues...

Comment: [Here's the story you quoted but didn't link](https://www.newsday.co.zw/2016/03/womens-university-sued-418-000-software-code-piracy/). Let me complete the sentence you partially quoted. "... to recover over $418 000 for allegedly illegally acquiring the firm’s source code from Microsoft without its consent." The consultancy "provided the institution with the enterprise wide university management software." This case does not appear to involve a university member using pirated software on their personal computer.

Comment: @Pont (I hadn't noted the OP was using a personal computer until I edited the OP's question.) We've established that universities are sued by vendors for unlicensed access to software. Moreover, I've noted that litigation might be difficult if unlicensed software is used on personal, rather than business, computer. We'd need a lawyer to establish whether the university has any liability for work conducted on the university's behalf using equipment not owned by the university. (Establishing that universities are typically reliant on staff using their own equipment would be a starting point.)

Answer (score -3):

No, it's not okay. What's the ultimate point of a PhD? To train you in how to perform research.

What are the best practices for producing ethical research? Not using pirated software, for a start. If you use pirated software in the production of your PhD thesis, it's entirely possible that your university will take action against you for violating academic integrity standards.

For example, in the [Australian Code of Responsible Conduct of Research](https://www.nhmrc.gov.au/about-us/publications/australian-code-responsible-conduct-research-2018#block-views-block-file-attachments-content-block-1), Rule 17 says:

> Comply with the relevant laws, regulations, disciplinary standards, ethics guidelines and institutional policies related to responsible research conduct. Ensure that appropriate approvals are obtained prior to the commencement of research, and that conditions of any approvals are adhered to during the course of research.

Since software piracy is illegal, knowingly using pirated software in your research would constitute a breach of this rule. Indeed, in their document "Guide to Managing and Investigating Potential Breaches of the Australian Code for the Responsible Conduct of Research, 2018", available for download from the page previously linked to, the definition of a breach of the code includes:

> Conducting research without the requisite approvals, permits or licences.

Comment: This bureaucratic answer does not answer the question, or incorporates moral or normative judgments that have no relevance to the question asked. It also makes bold statements that are subjective or illogical. For example: *"What are the best practices for producing ethical software? Not using pirated software, for a start."* -- But the OP didn't ask about practices for producing ethical software at all.

Comment: @Dilworth Corrected typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not sure why this Answer is getting downvoted. It’s true, it’s about the ethical aspects of the Question, and it’s backing it up with citations from relevant regulatory documents that Australian universities base the relevant portions of their Manuals of Policies and Procedures on. It’s not quite a quote from a professional organisation’s Code of Ethics, but it’s pretty close.

Comment: I did not point out a typo, but a conceptual error in the answer: you assume by mistake that the OP is interested to perform "ethical research", but this is not part of the question.

Comment: @Dilworth Producing ethical research is literally what a PhD is intended to train you to do. If you're behaving unethically when you're doing your PhD, you're likely to get punished by your institution if they catch you, assuming you're going somewhere even remotely reputable.

Comment: no. PhD is a programme that trains you to become an independent researcher in a given field. It has nothing to do with doing ethical stuff. Indeed, the research itself should be ethical only so to prove that you have indeed become an independent researchers (for instance, not plagiarized your thesis). A murderer for example can do a PhD and become an independent researcher, even if the murder occurred while writing the dissertation.

Comment: @Dilworth Somehow I doubt that you’ll be getting the IRB to agree to letting you to murder someone for your PhD thesis. There’s a difference between unethical behaviour that might occur alongside your research, and unethical behaviour that occurs as part of your research.

Comment: I agree. Using a pirated software is not something that occurs as part of the research, in that it does not affect the integrity of the outcome of the research nor the independence of the researcher. Only the methods can be said to be "dubious".

Comment: @Dilworth If you're using the pirated software as part of the methodology (data collection, processing, simulation, or what have you), then you're tainting  your research with the crime you've committed. It'd be like murdering someone to write a paper about their corpse, just a lot less severe.